# Cron job executing in Jenkins DSL

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-job-dsl, smoke-testing

I am trying to create a cron job which run some smoke tests every 10 minutes, my seedjob looks like this :

```
multiBranchJobs.each { currentJob ->
    multibranchPipelineJob(currentJob.name) {
        branchSources {
            git {
                remote(currentJob.projectGitUrl)
                credentialsId(currentJob.credentials)
                includes(currentJob.includes)
            }
        }
        orphanedItemStrategy {
            discardOldItems {
                numToKeep(20)
            }
        }
        triggers {
            cron "H/5 * * * *"
            periodic 60
        }
    }
}
```

the problem with the current approach is that it will get executes only if it detects changes in the SCM, which is not the case for the smoke tests. I need to run it every 5 minutes regardless of commits in source control. Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to solve your problem, but I think the cron trigger you have is not doing what you think it is. I THINK this will set this trigger on the multibranch indexing job itself. In the UI that is not even an option. Apparently it isn't throwing an error, but I have to wonder if it is actually setting the trigger.

The jobs that get created from the multibranch job must have a Jenkinsfile, right? You can set the triggers in those Jenkinsfiles.

I haven't built jobs using code, so take that into consideration when you review my answer. But it SEEMS to me that you are setting the trigger in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, the trigger should be defined in Jenkinsfile, see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Comment: changing the created job into a pipelineJob did the trick, because multibranchPipelineJob triggers a SCM scan to check if there is new commit.